# Series Data as Array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, highcharts

I tried searching for the answer. I am sure it is very simple and basic, but I haven't been able to find anything on topic.

I have an array of integers I have gotten from a php query. I use this to transfer the data from php to javascript:

```
      var Hour07 = <?php echo json_encode($hour07); ?>;
```

If I do document.write(Hour07[0]); it outputs the number to the screen, so I can see that is storing data.

When I do this:

```
series: [{
          name: '7am',
          data: Hour07
        }]
```

Nothing comes up. If I replace Hour07 with [10,10,10] the chart displays correctly. It seems that it just doesn't like the array, although it took an array for categories . I have read various postings and some suggested converting the array to integer first which I tried.

Comment: If you do a `var_dump` of `$hour07`, what is the output?

Comment: `document.write` does stringify its arguments, which is probably undesired. Either wrap it in `JSON.stringify`, or just use `console.log(series)` instead

Comment: array (size=12)
  0 => string '1059' (length=4)
  1 => string '0' (length=1)
  2 => string '0' (length=1)
  3 => string '66' (length=2)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  6 => string '0' (length=1)
  7 => string '0' (length=1)
  8 => string '0' (length=1)
  9 => string '0' (length=1)
  10 => string '0' (length=1)
  11 => string '0' (length=1)

Comment: So array was string and I needed to convert it to integer. I am sure this isn't the best way, but this is what worked for me. I changed my while loop that reads the MySQL results to this:                                                                          $hour07[$counter] = $row['07'];                                                              settype($hour07[$counter], "integer");

Comment: Take look at http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing. Your data needs to be intereger